# Liferay - Show spinner while page is loading

Tags: jsf, liferay, liferay-6

I have a portlet (only one portlet on the page) and want to show a spinner (or hourglass) while the user waits for a request.

Setting the `render-weight` to `0` in `liferay-portlet.xml` works, but then the CSS classes aren't loaded and the url parameters aren't parsed anymore.

Is there another solution for that?

[I'm running Liferay 6.1.20 EE]

Thanks in advance,
Fabi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using jQuery, I can set the `cursor` to `wait` whenever the user clicks on a link:

```
jqueryBusy = function(){
     $("a").click(function() {
            $("*").css("cursor", "wait");
     });
};
```

I call this function when the page loads and somethink simmelar, whenever a ajax request is busy:

```
if (!window["busystatus"]) {
    var busystatus = {};
}

busystatus.onStatusChange = function onStatusChange(data) {
    var status = data.status;

    jqueryBusy(); //set jquery event handler for all links

    if (status === "begin") { // turn on busy indicator
        document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
    } else { // turn off busy indicator, on either "complete" or "success"
        document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
    }
};

jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(busystatus.onStatusChange);
```

Works for me.